# Using for loop to simplify codes in python3

Tags: python

Could someone help me simplify this code? Thank you very much!

```
if local_board[1][1] == local_board[1][2] == local_board[1][3] != ' 'or \
        local_board[2][1] == local_board[2][2] == local_board[2][3] != ' 'or \
        local_board[3][1] == local_board[3][2] == local_board[3][3] != ' 'or \
        local_board[1][1] == local_board[2][1] == local_board[3][1] != ' 'or \
        local_board[1][2] == local_board[2][2] == local_board[3][2] != ' 'or \
        local_board[1][3] == local_board[2][3] == local_board[3][3] != ' 'or \
        local_board[1][1] == local_board[2][2] == local_board[3][3] != ' 'or \
        local_board[1][3] == local_board[2][2] == local_board[3][1] != ' ':
```

Comment: Stack overflow isn't really a code writing service. Try to see if you can find a general rule for the logic first and see if it works

Comment: I agree with Arch2K, but one recommendation I'll make is to be highly cautious around `or` statements.  Always use parentheses to make it **very** explicit what your or applies to.

Comment: this can't be simplify with single `for`-loop. You could need one loop for rows, one loop for columns and still stays two diagonals. But code can be more complex or less readable. But you could try to do it - you will see if it simpler for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

First build a list of coordinate triples:

```
lines = [ [(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)], [(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)], [(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)],
          [(1,1),(2,1),(3,1)], [(1,2),(2,2),(3,2)], [(1,3),(2,3),(3,3)],
          [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)], [(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)]
        ]
```

Then loop through these coordinate triples to detect the winning condition:

```
win == False
for line in lines:
    squares = [local_board[r][c] for r,c in line]
    if all(s == squares[0] for s in squares) and squares[0] != " ":
        win = True; break
```

*Note that python lists use zero-based indexes, your logic must be doing some unnatural shenanigans to use 1,2,3 instead of 0,1,2 for the positions.  This is going to make it hard to use Python's default behaviours (e.g. range()) in your code*